# programmatically decide which style attribute to modify in javascript

Tags: javascript, styles, self-modifying

I have a situation where, depending on a variable value, I will want to modify EITHER the margin-top OR margin-bottom property of a div.

Apart from using an "if else", is there any way of doing it kinda like this :

```
var whichmargin="marginTop";
document.getElementById('myElement').style.whichmargin = '100px';
```

If you get what I mean lol ?

By the way, I am using vanilla JS rather than jQuery.

I don't want to use SetAttribute as I don't want to alter any other of the div style.

Any ideas much appreciated:

Comment: What's wrong with an `if-else` statement?

Comment: Nothing wrong with an if-else, just a bit less code this way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the [] syntax:

```
var value = 'somethingelse';
var whichmargin = value === 'something' ? "marginTop" : "marginBottom";
document.getElementById('myElement').style[whichmargin] = '100px';
```

Comment: Yesss!!!  Thank you so much - I KNEW I had done it before but couldn't remember :)  MUCH Appreciated.